# glibc got downgraded by mistake

Tags: 14.04, glibc

I installed a debian package along with its dependencies using an automated script. However, this happened to install an older version of glibc (2.15) and thereby I assume overrode the version that was originally running 2.17/2.18.

Now it looks like the entire computer is broken - the filsystem doesn't mount properly...

```
General error mounting filesystems.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
```

...half the common programs (ls, apt-get) won't work since they look for libc 2.17 or libc 2.18 and it reboots in a state with the filesystem read-only.

I tried to download and reinstall libc 2.17 but the network won't start up and it won't recognize any external flash drives. What can I do now?

Thanks